# How to compute cosine similarity between two texts in presto?

Tags: sql, presto, text-processing, cosine-similarity, trino

Hello everyone: I wanted to use COSINE_SIMILARITY in Presto SQL to compute the similarity between two texts. Unfortunately, COSINE_SIMILARITY does not take the texts as the inputs; it takes maps instead. I am not sure how to convert the texts into those maps in presto. I want the following, if we have a table like this:

| id | text1 | text2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a b b | b c |

Then we can compute the cosine similarity as:

```
COSINE_SIMILARITY(
    MAP(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'], ARRAY[1, 2, 0]),
    MAP(ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'], ARRAY[0, 1, 1])
)
```

i.e., two texts combined has three words: 'a', 'b', and 'c'; text1 has 1 count of 'a', 2 counts of 'b', and 0 count of 'c', which goes as the first MAP; similarly, text2 has 0 count of 'a', 1 count of 'b', and 1 count of 'c', which goes as the second MAP.

The final table should look like this:

| id | text1 | text2 | all_unique_words | map1 | map2 | similarity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a b b | b c | [a b c] | [1, 2, 0] | [0, 1, 1] | 0.63 |

How can we convert two texts into two such maps in presto? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split` to transform string into array and then depended on Presto version either use `unnest`+`histogram` trick or `array_frequency`:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(id, text1, text2) as (values (1, 'a b b', 'b c'))

-- query
select id, COSINE_SIMILARITY(histogram(t1), histogram(t2))
from dataset,
unnest (split(text1, ' '), split(text2, ' ')) as t(t1, t2)
group by id;
```

Output:

| id | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6324555320336759 |

**UPD**

For Trino in the latest version [`array_histogram` function](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/14725) should be added.